# Python - Checking for Null Object

Tags: python, object, null

I'm new to Python and I don't understand how this works. I would like to assign a value to an object in Python if it is currently undefined, but when I run the if statement, it fails because the object isn't defined (Duh.).

<strike>How would I fix this?</strike>

```
...
key = raw_input('What is your key?: ')

for i in key:
    print i
    if Count is None:
        Count = 0 

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Client.py", line 7, in <module>
    if Count is None:
NameError: name 'Count' is not defined
```

What can I do to fix this seemingly easy issue?

The above code was garbage and was something I was testing for understanding of basic Python functionality. It brought me back to the issue of assigning a value to an object which is an issue I've had before. Below is my thought process.

Ok, so obviously I'm not explaining something well enough here. I'm not sure what it is, but something irks me about having to assign a value to an object that is not yet relevant. 
For readability alone, I would like to check for a null value of an object before it is used in a statement. From what I've read below, it's going to be necessary and something I'm most likely just going to have to deal with. In my mind, this...

```
...
object = 'ObligatoryValue'

for i in Data
    Object = Data[0] # Now the object is relevant
    ...
```

looks better than this...

```
...
for i in Data
    if Object is None:
        Object = Data[0] 
    ...
```

To even further explain the reasoning, I work in data manipulation. And the first time I ran into this issue was when I was comparing two objects. If attempted to do something like...

```
...
Object = Line[0]
if UndefinedObject == Object
    do = 'something'
...
```

But I would always have an error returned because UndefinedObject was not assigned a value.

Comment: You can't. Assignment *is* defining the name. You can check if a global has been assigned to, but you generally don't. What is your usecase?

Comment: You can assign `None` to `Count` first; add `Count = None` at the top, but there is litte point, really.

Comment: @Simeon "Count" is the object I would like to check the value of. I would like to assign a value to it if it has not previously been assigned a value.

Comment: @vbiqvitovs: Why do you need to do that? Why not assign to it to begin with?

Comment: What would be the best method for this type of logical progression?

Comment: @Martijn I would like to not assign a value to an object until it has intrinsic value, which in this case would be in the for statement.

Comment: If the object has no intrinsic value before this point, what is there to check? Just assign `Count = 0` unconditionally in the loop. If it _does_ have an intrinsic value, but that intrinsic value is "empty", create it before the loop with the value `None`, as in Martijn's answer. In other words, normal Python code maps "has an intrinsic value" to "exists as a variable".

Comment: @vbiqvitovs: But **why don't you want to assign a value**? That is what explicitly assigning `None` is *for*.

Comment: Please read [What is the XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). There's obviously some reason you want to do this. If we knew that reason, I'd give about 1000:1 odds we could explain to you a better way to do the same thing.

Comment: @abarnert There is something about prior assignment that I don't like. It doesn't make sense to me that I would have to assign a value to the object outside of the statement in which it's going to have value. I'll summarize my thoughts on this in my original post.

Comment: @vbiqvitovs: Normally, you _don't_ have to assign a value outside the statement. You only need to do so here because you want to "check for null object", and the null object is a value, so you have to assign it so you can later check for it. You're putting that requirement on yourself, most likely because of a larger design choice in the code you're actually trying to write.

Comment: @abarnert I work heavily in data/file manipulation. Having an interest in programming I see parts of my data entry position that can be automated. The first time I ran into this issue was when I was comparing two objects but I couldn't get the statement to return true of false because the object was undefined.

Comment: @vbiqvitovs: If you're "comparing two objects", the objects can't be undefined. There is no way to compare an undefined object, or do anything else with an undefined object, because there is no expression in Python that refers to an undefined object. There are expressions that refer to null objects (that is, `None`), and expressions that don't refer to anything because they're errors, but neither of those is an undefined object.

Answer (score 5):

You can set `Count` to `None` explicitly, first:

```
Count = None

for i in key:
   if Count is None:
       Count = 0
```

but in this case it would be easier to just assign `0` to begin with:

```
Count = 0

for i in key:
```

Answer (score 2):

This is almost certainly a very bad idea. As everyone explained in comments, and Martijn Pieters's answer shows, there's a better way to do almost anything you want to do.

Also, this is *not* "Checking for Null Object". The "null object" is `None`. Martijn's answer shows how to do that. This is checking for a variable not being bound at all, not for a variable being bound to the null object.

Anyway, Python doesn't prevent you from doing this, it just doesn't make it easy (because it's *almost* always a bad idea, but occasionally necessary).

So, here's how to do it:

```
for i in key:
    try:
        Count
    except NameError:
        Count = 0
```

Or, if you need to know whether it exists at a particular scope—e.g., you only care if there's a *global* `Count`, not a `Count` anywhere:

```
for i in key:
    if 'Count' not in globals():
        Count = 0
```

Or you can use `hasattr` or `getattr` on the appropriate namespace.

Comment: I like the second statement you have there. It seems more clean to me. Excuse my ignorance in regards to the basic use of Python. I've only been working with it for a few days. Thank you for this.

Comment: @vbiqvitovs: I was explicitly avoiding telling you about how exactly you can do that (I only stated it was possible). It generally indicates you are trying to do something you really shouldn't or at the very least don't need to do at all. You can swim against the flow, but why exert yourself so much doing so?

Comment: @vbiqvitovs: If you've only been using Python for a few days, I'm even _more_ certain you don't want to do this. I'm guessing either you're a novice programmer, or coming from Javascript, where testing against `undefined` is idiomatic and common, right? Explain what you're actually trying to do, and we can show you how to do it well in Python, instead of showing you how to use Python as a bad version of JavaScript.

Answer (score -2):

You could define it as an empty string before you can check:

```
Count = ''
```

then later on you can test...

```
if not Count:
    Count = 0;
```

Comment: Why would you define it to an empty string instead of, say, `None`, the idiomatic "empty value" in Python, as already shown n Martijn Pieters's answer?

Comment: Though the end result is the same... the "if not Count:" bit is more logically consistent with what the original question was trying to do (if count hasn't been assigned a value yet then assign it a value".

at least that would be my opinion...

Comment: It's more logically consistent with the original than something which is _identical_ to the original? Besides, this check doesn't even work, because `not Count` is just as true for `0` as it is for `''`.

Comment: `not Count` will still be true when you set it to `0`. Numeric zero is *also* false, so your version will set `Count` to 0 perpetualy, unless `Count` is assigned other values later on.